# Custom KeyManager and TrustManager for Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, trustmanager, x509trustmanager

I have decided to rebrand my question, I am looking for a way to provide a custom keymanager and trustmanager for my Spring Boot application.
Basically I have an application that provides users with custom URLs for example:
https://user1.mydomain.com https://user2.mydomain.com etc these url are forward to my spring boot application, and as each user connects to his/her custom url a different SSL certificate is presented. so i want to makesure i serve a different SSL certificate for each connection a backend store of the certificate should be a database or ldap.

any ideas?